# MySQL return print in array twice

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to get MySQL to put everything into a array which would be easier for me to work with later down the road.

I currently am using the following

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM  (SELECT * FROM new WHERE qc_status =\'pending\' AND call_date = \''.date("Y-m-d").'\' LIMIT 0,17) as assesmenttable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1',$link);
                        $array = array();

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                            foreach($row as $column => $value) {
                                $array[$column]= $value;
                            }
                        }
                        print_r($array);
                }
```

but the issue is it is giving me an array like this

```
Array ( [0] => Ms [title] => Ms [1] => Belinda [fname] => Belinda
```

clearly it is doing something wrong; I want the array to look like this

```
array([title]=>Ms, [fname]=>Belinda)
```

In json_encode it should look like this

```
{title:Ms,fname:Belinda}
```

Would someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both       use mysql_assoc instead

Comment: You can use MYSQL_ASSOC as 2nd param for mysql_fetch_array() or use mysql_fetch_assoc(), but please take time to read the big red warning in the manual about mysql_ functions.

Answer (score 2):

[mysql_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) is using `MYSQL_BOTH` as the `result_type` by default giving you both - associative and number indices.

You have to use `MYSQL_ASSOC` as the result_type to get your result array with only associative indices:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  // your code
}
```